# Require Android UI patterns for making a choice between Camera and Gallery

Tags: design-patterns, android, choices

In my app, I am looking to give the user a choice between two equal actions;

1. choosing to take a picture with a camera, or
2. selecting an image from the gallery.

I am looking for a suitable UI pattern that show this choice or a choice between two equal options.

Can you recommend any patterns for this?

I think my initial question was too broad, narrowing it down:

1. the screen is full screen
2. there is no other functional element on the screen as this choice is the first choice the user has to make
3. these choices are equal in sense that they lead to the same ending point via different routes

Answer (score 2):

As I see it there are two main flow strategies to choose from, and interestingly two of the large players have implemented one each:

[image]

Facebook has one call to action from the news feed, namely "Photo". When a user goes into that flow they are initially presented with their album to make a selection. To capture a new photo there is a CTA to the camera at the bottom action bar.

[image]

Twitter presents the two options at one when a user starts the "post flow". Both CTA's for either posting an image from the album or posting an image captured by the camera are instantly accessible.

This is a matter of "crowd control". Both apps feature an action bar with three actions, if Facebook were to separate the **Capture photo** from **Grab from Album** they would produce an action bar with four actions. To keep it minimal and more visually simplistic (interaction wise it does get a bit more complex with this pattern though) they have combined the two actions in the same flow.

Comment: Thanks for the answer,this is an interesting solution(solves anoher problem of mine),can you show me a screen where the user(unfortunately) has no other choice but these two actions...cta=Call To Action right?

Comment: @user2309862 Yes, CTA is an abbreviation for Call To Action and refers to the cue element (icon or label) that describes an action. I'm not sure about existing contexts where these two are the only options, I could imagine Instagram has a flow for this, unfortunately I ended my account years ago.

Comment: No,they dont,their UI looks like this [Instagram](https://lh4.ggpht.com/fc3aCOb6CPdISEl6YQbX0XtoJB2O5INjz5DcItUwj7v2wXauITvSDOE3CQV9ddpyIgc=h900-rw)

Comment: I present here my other findings: [Choice screens](https://www.evernote.com/shard/s218/sh/89d1da2d-19cc-4589-b878-5931475667fb/1724ffced6efc696e7d160c33e1cc358)

Comment: @user2309862 Oh, ok, där ser man! =)
You could probably have a look at the foap app as well, it's photo oriented.